# Hibernate and Jersey dependency conflict (javassist) - can anyone explain how this works?

Tags: java, hibernate, jersey, dependency-management

I'm currently using hibernate-4.1.4 and jersey-2.22. These have javassist-3.15 and javassist-3.18 respectively.

I included both hibernate and jersey in my project and to my surprise, there were no dependency conflicts between the said javassists.

I was wondering how Java tells hibernate to use 3.15 and how it tell jersey to use 3.18 since both are in the build path. Is one javassist not being used?

Follow up question: Let's say that javassist-3.15 and javassist-3.18 have a conflict with each other. How do I resolve this? Do I disable both javassists and include one externally?

EDIT: My app is a web app that runs on Tomcat 7. We don't use Maven/Gradle. We just configure the dependencies by putting the jars in the build path using Eclipse.

Comment: What are you using to import those libraries into your project?? Maven?

Comment: Nope, I'm not using Maven. We're just including jars to the Eclipse build path. Right click project -> Properties -> Build Path -> Add external jar. I know it's weird but that's how it is

Comment: Your application is a standalone JAVA App ?? o It is an enterprise App (WEB, EJB, ...) that runs in a special container (Tomcat, JBoss, etc)...

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific. It's a web application that runs on Tomcat 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAVA loads classes through ClassLoaders ... Many applications servers, as Tomcat or Wildfly, implement and use their own class loaders (not the regular ones of the common JDK) ... So you must check the Tomcat documentation to read about its classloading behaviour...

After saying that, is very likely that Tomcat is loading libraries in alphabetical order. I Explain...

Suppose that you use a class named: `Dummy`, and this class is contained at the libraries: `dummy-1.0.jar` and `dummy-1.1.jar` ... when the class `Dummy` is requested, the Tomcat ClassLoader search for that class definition, looking first at `dummy-1.0.jar` and later at `dummy-1.1.jar`  ... given that `dummy-1.0.jar` contains that class, Tomcat stops looking a returns that class version ... If `dummy-1.0.jar` would not have the target class, the `dummy-1.1.jar` class version would be returned instead...

(I suggest to try this to validate the container behaivour, it's not so hard to implement)...

And yes, if `javassist-3.15` and `javassist-3.18` conflicts with each other, you should remove them and pick the javassist JAR more
suitable for both libraries (jersey and hibernate).

As thumb rule, I tend to pick the newest library (the one with greater version), but this scheme not always work...

Comment: And yes, if javassist-3.15 and javassist-3.18 conflicts with each other, you should remove them and pick the javassist JAR more
suitable for both libraries (jersey and hibernate).

So how would I know if a specific version of javassist is suitable for both Hibernate and Jersey? Where would I find that information?

If you were in my position and the javassist jars had a conflict, what would you do?

Comment: First, I would try to check if the associated project sites have such information available. If not, I would try asking in their respective mailing list... 

Also, I would try to pick one javaassist, and test my application completely (full regresion) ... If no errors or exceptions (linked to hibernate/javaassist or jersey/javaassist) arise, then that version library is a good candidate to be winner library...

Comment: If the javassist jars had a conflict, I will explore the following options: One, Find a hibernate version and jersey version that use the same javaasist, and allows me to run my code with the minimun changes.  Two, Verify why I need jersey and hibernate together, Can I separate the classes that use hibernate from those that use jersey, and exposes them as services?? Three, see how can I call hibernate and jersey using isolated classloaders (This is very hard, but there are projects that atack this kind of problem, example: JBoss Modules)